MapRequestPayload cannot map a nested object request body to an Entity
I'm developing a Symfony app and want to use the MapRequestPayload attribute to map the following JSON payload
{
  "article": {
    "title": "How to train your dragon",
    "description": "Ever wonder how?",
    "body": "You have to believe",
  }
}

into the following Dto
class ArticleDto
{
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[Assert\NotNull]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[Assert\NotNull]
    private ?string $body = null;

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): static
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): static
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBody(): ?string
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function setBody(string $body): static
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }
}

Here's also the controller method
    #[Route('', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function store(#[MapRequestPayload] ArticleDto $dto): JsonResponse
    {
        $article = $this->articleService->store($dto);

        return $this->json([
            'article' => $article,
        ], 201);
    }

Upon invoking the controller method a 422 response is returned with errors on all params that should not be null.
The MapRequestPayload attribute does not know how to map that request body to a DTO.
How could I customize it to properly map that structure?

The payload does not match the DTO (it has a main object and a nested object).
